# Each module has to have a unique path

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I have imported a project from version control using GIT. After importing, syncing and all that, it gave me this error:

> Error:The modules 'LinkedCraftMobile', 'linkedcraft_android' point to same directory in the file system.
>   Each module has to have a unique path.

I wanted to have a module that can be updated directly with GIT using Android Studio.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

2016: It could be because of a `.gitmodules` including two entries with the same paths, but [square/assertj-android issues 174](https://github.com/square/assertj-android/issues/174) points out to another file:

> > This usually is the result of old `iml` files. Delete them all and re-import.
>
> Weird, removing the `.iml` and reimporting worked.

Update 2020: as [commented by ArashYounesi in issue 174](https://github.com/square/assertj-android/issues/174#issuecomment-650779148), Android Studio V4.0 seems to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to fix the .iml files (by recreating them) is to do this:

1. Close the project in Android Studio
2. In Android Studio, `New > Import Project`

That fixed it for me, and it was a lot easier than the other stuff I tried (and a lot less complex).

I believe that rewrites the .iml files with you do that.

What did I try? I tried `Build > clean/rebuild project`, `File > Invalidate caches/restart`, and `Sync Project with Gradle Files`. I was going to manually erase my .iml files but then I found out about this solution and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

**The best way to fix this problem is:**

Go to Tools-> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of .iml file conflict, For fixing the issue you just need to clean the project and rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers helped me.
So i Updated my android studio and it solved (Now i have android studio V4.0)

Comment: I too regularly getting this error and solution above fixed my problem until recently it started to not working. I too tried deleting and re installing node_modules .iml files etc. Updating android studio was a fresh breeze thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my project settings.gradle,there's a "rootProject.name" attribute assigned,but it does't equals with my project name.I modified this attribute with my project name,then the error message dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest Android Studio solved it. I upgraded to Android Studio v4.0.1

Answer (score -1):

I have same issue , and i tried 
`bulid >clean / rebulid`  and `Tools > Androdi > sync project with gradle file`but it doesn't works for me.

and then I tried `File >Invalidate Caches / Restart ...`and it is works  for me .

[image]