# Gradle build fail because of react native mail

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to generate signed APK file with Android Studio and the build is failing.

The error I get is : 
**"ERROR: The modules ['android-RNMail', 'android-react-native-mail'] point to the same directory in the file system.
Each module must have a unique path."**

this is my android/app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js",
        enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 9
        versionName "2.1"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a","arm64-v8a","x86","x86_64"
            exclude "ldpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
            release {
                // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
                // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
                minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                shrinkResources enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
            pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':react-native-google-signin')
        compile project(':react-native-action-sheet')
        compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
        compile project(':react-native-android-location-enabler')
        compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
        compile project(':react-native-restart')
        compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
        compile project(':react-native-calendar-events')
        compile project(':react-native-mail')
        compile project(':react-native-branch')
        compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
        compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
        compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
        compile project(':react-native-svg')
        compile project(':react-native-geocoder')
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'

        implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin"))
        compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
            transitive = false
        }

        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0"
        implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
        implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        implementation("com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0")
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
                force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
                force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
                force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
            }
        }

        implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
        }
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'

        implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'

        if (enableHermes) {
            def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
            debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
            releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
        } else {
            implementation jscFlavor
        }
    }

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
    task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'libs'
    }

    apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");
    applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Also, after each build, a null.iml file is generated in android/app directory.

I did not find any solution but removing .iml files, which did not helped at all. 
Invalidate cahces and restart also did not helped.

What can be the reason for those problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Each module has to have a unique path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629692/each-module-has-to-have-a-unique-path)